# LeaveCriticalSection. breakpoint in malloc function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, malloc, heap-memory

in this part of my code:

```
Pixel** inputPattern2D = (Pixel**)malloc(sizeof(Pixel*) * 500000);
```

my program has stopped with error in **osfinfo.c**:

```
void __cdecl _unlock_fhandle (
    int fh
    )
{
    LeaveCriticalSection( &(_pioinfo(fh)->lock) );
}
```

and write: 
*Heap has been damaged*

I think, that the problem is in memory that allocated to project, but i don't know, how to increase this in Visual Studio =(

Callstack:

```
Win32ConsEmpty.exe!_unlock_fhandle(int fh)
Win32ConsEmpty.exe!_unlock(int locknum)
000001db()  
Win32ConsEmpty.exe!_heap_alloc_base(unsigned int size)
Win32ConsEmpty.exe!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl(unsigned int nSize, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp)
Win32ConsEmpty.exe!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl(unsigned int nSize, int nhFlag, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine, int * errno_tmp)
Win32ConsEmpty.exe!_nh_malloc_dbg(unsigned int nSize, int nhFlag, int nBlockUse, const char * szFileName, int nLine)
Win32ConsEmpty.exe!malloc(unsigned int nSize)
Win32ConsEmpty.exe!PatternRecognition()
```

Comment: Is this a 32-bit program? How much memory is your program using before the attempted `malloc`?

Comment: What is the callstack when the exception is raised?

Comment: You have corrupted the heap

Comment: I work with images: download, modify, etc... When i downnload a small image? it's OK. But when I increase size of image, i have a error. I'm Sorry, but I don't know, how to measure memory my program using.

Comment: David Heffernan, I guessed =) Visual Studio say it to me)

Comment: How big is "Pixel"? - I'd say that 500K pixels isn't huge (2MB if Pixel is 32 bits), so it's unlikely that it's this allocation itself that is the problem. Rather, some allocation before has gone wrong [e.g. you are overwriting the end of the allocation], and it's showing up at this point.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, you mean, what I went out of bounds before?

Comment: Yes, most likely. This kind of crash is a typical example of "we crash here because something that went wrong earlier".

Comment: The `_unlock_fhandle` is a red herring.  You've likely smashed the stack, as evidenced by the `000001db` frame.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, it can be entertaining, thanks, i try to check this

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, U're right! But how I can smashed? Only Mats Petersson was explained me.

Comment: Thoughts smart people converge! Thanks, Guys, U A explained me my problem. I went out of bounds earlier, smashed something, and my program go to Critical Section. After it can not return to normal work and FAIL! red herring( quote=) ) and I think, what it all happended because I have no enought memory.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: problem has been checked. It is "out of bounds"